# G1ANT SDK installation for VS 2019

Tags: g1ant

I cloned the repository at [the G1ANT.Robot github page](https://github.com/G1ANT-Robot/G1ANT.Sdk) and opened G1ANT.Sdk.sln in VS Studio 2019 CE 16.1.5, Win10 Pro with latest updates. I left the default build properties as "Debug" and "AnyCPU". The following error can't be resolved, as I don't have the required files on my system:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning     Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Microsoft.VisualStudio.CoreUtility, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.   G1ANT.AddonTemplate
```

There are other errors, all seemingly related to dependencies on an earlier version or versions of VS (some I believe to be v14.0 dependent, some to be v15.0 dependent).

I do have the Microsoft.VisualStudio.CoreUtility available, but the version is 16.0 (i.e. VS 2019). In short, it appears that compilation may require an earlier version of VS than the one I have. Installing such an earlier version is not an option for me.

Thanks,
burque505

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, file /G1ANT.Sdk/G1ANT.Sdk/source.extension.vsixmanifest should be changed:

```
<Installation>
    <InstallationTarget Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community" Version="[15.0,]" />
    <InstallationTarget Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro" Version="[15.0,]" />
    <InstallationTarget Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Enterprise" Version="[15.0,]" />
</Installation>
<Dependencies>
    <Dependency Id="Microsoft.Framework.NDP" DisplayName="Microsoft .NET Framework" d:Source="Manual" Version="[4.6.1,)" />
</Dependencies>
```

You can download the correct installation: https://github.com/G1ANT-Robot/G1ANT.Sdk/raw/master/G1ANT.Sdk.vsix

I believe it will help :)

Comment: Installing the VSIX referenced worked for me on Win10 Pro, latest updates, VS 2019 CE, and on Win7 Pro SP1, 64-bit, both VS 2019 CE and VS 2017 CE.